# Gulp vinyl ftp - Remove local deleted files

Tags: ftp, gulp, vinyl

I use vinyl ftp to deploy my project on remote server. No problem to upload files but i would also like to delete files that aren't anymore in local folder.

Example :

Local folder

```
./
fileA
fileB
fileC
```

Remote folder :

```
./
fileB
fileC
fileD
```

What i have in remote folder for the moment after deploy :

```
./
fileA
fileB
fileC
fileD
```

What i would like (exactly same as local folder) :

```
./
fileA
fileB
fileC
```

I could use rmdir to delete all files but that implies to reupload all files for each deploy.

Thank you

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't look like its implemented yet:

https://github.com/morris/vinyl-ftp/issues/33

(2016-06-20) edit by @ajoah: **It's implemented since version [0.5.0](https://github.com/morris/vinyl-ftp/releases) through [clean function](https://github.com/morris/vinyl-ftp#connclean-globs-local-options--stream).**

Comment: That's why i didn't found a solution ^^. Thank you for the link. (for the moment i delete the folder sometimes)